# How to upload only latest modified files easily?

Tags: deployment, localhost, bitbucket, frontend, web-deployment

Since I'm a designer and also a mid-level front professional, nowadays I still upload all my projects the old way, through filezilla or brackets, using a basic FTP extension. The problem is that it takes a lot of time especially when I don't remember exactly which files I've changed recently, I mean, I have no idea about how web developers actually do to push their projects quickly. Once I'm working with e-commerce projects with thousands of files (magento), I need to make my work look more professional.

I always listen "someone will deploy the modifications" etc, but I'm still breezing on that, because I'm not an advanced front developer.

So, what is the easiest but professional way to upload (or deploy, whatever) files that I've changed recently to a production server? I would like to use Bitbucket, so I can have a full control about the project and also to have a backup of it.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bitbucket is your repository, you should read up on how to use GIT effectively. Typically with our projects, we use 3 branches, each branch is connected to a different environment:

Development: Connected to our development environment

Staging: Connected to our staging environment

Production: Connected to the client's production environment

The development environment is where the various developers commit their code once developed locally. The changes are internally tested, once approved, they are committed to the staging branch.

The staging environment is typically the most like the production environment, another round of testing is conducted including UAT (user acceptance testing). Once approved the changes are scheduled for deployment to production. We have processes in place that ensures that not just anyone can commit changes to the production branch.

There are various ways to deploy changes to production; if your code control is effective, then typically your production branch should always be a reflection of the production environment. You can deploy in a number of ways:

1. Manually: Using BitBucket/Github etc effectively should allow you to tag all changes to the repo, you will then have to manually upload them to production, based on the tag.
2. Deployment System: Using a deployment system such as [Jenkins](https://jenkins.io/) or [Bitbucket Pipelines](https://bitbucket.org/product/features/pipelines) is I believe the best way to go. once setup, it allows for easy deployment, straight from your repository. It also keeps track of previous deployments and if there were any issues which is great for accountability.

Comment: Great, I will take a look. Actually I already worked with Bitbucket but hadn't  used a deploy process. Which one do you think its more effective, Jenkins or Bitbucket Pipelines? Do we able to send files to production from Bitbucket directly? Thanks man!

Comment: I haven't personally used Bitbucket Pipelines and is a relatively new product. I have used Jenkins and found it pretty effective. I would personally go with Pipelines, only because it is a product of BitBucket and has the potential to be a leading deployment tool in the future.